# Ubuntu 18.04 LTS Bionic Beaver: Samsung Printer/Scanner M2070 via USB cannot print, can only scan

Tags: drivers, usb, printing, samsung

Into the topic "How to setup Samsung M2070FW network scanner" I found a fine answer that helps on how to set up the Scanner, but not the printer.
Now I need help to set up the print action.
I tried many suggestions, but no one finally works up to now.
Once installed the 'Unified Driver Configurator' from Samsung, the printer is visible. 
When trying to use "Test..." function, a pop-up error appears as "the document format application/vnd.cups-pdf-banner is not supported" (or something like this, I translated the message from Italian).
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Using the command line like:

Comment: By using a command line like:

'lp -d M2070 /etc/apt/sources.lit'

the printer works fine, but no way to print by ising, e.g. a libreoffice document.

Answer (score 0):

I followed these simple steps:

1. Direct printing with the command line 
   '*lp -d M2070 filename*'
   has been successful (text-only mode).
2. The driver properties shows 'generic text-only printer'.
   For this reason the raw printing was successful.
3. Go to the following URL https://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/supported.html that contains official info about Samsung Unified Linux Drivers Repository to be used.
4. For the M2070 Samsung multifunction printer, inside the 'Monochrome Laser Printers, multifunction (MFP-, SCX-, SF-, M & K & X (SL-, Xpress, ProXpress))' table, the 1.00.36 (driver2) is suggested.
5. Please refer to the same Driver (1.00.36 (driver2)) type and take in consideration the M267x PPD Series that can use the same driver.
6. Access the configuration printer property and select a driver for the M2070 Printer.
   From the Driver list available, select 'Samsung' from the left list manufacturer and the M267x M287x Model.

Printer Test Page was successful.